# nivo slider in php / html

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm new and I've searched the forums for something similar... but I've not found any advice that could help me in my coding.

I'm trying to implement the Nivo Slider into my website.. But it is giving me errors or doing nothing at all.

My website is based off a CMS program, so I have to login as admin to edit the page.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated..

Here's what I've done on the php file linking to the website. :

```
    <?php   defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied."); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo LANGUAGE?>">

<head>

<?php   Loader::element('header_required'); ?>

<!-- Site Header Content //-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getThemePath()?>/css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getStyleSheet('main.css')?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getStyleSheet('typography.css')?>" />
<!-- Print Area Style //-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="<?php echo $this->getStyleSheet('printer.css')?>" />


  <style type="text/css">
    UL#ariext89 LI A{font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;text-transform:none;text-align:left;}
  </style>

</script>
</head>

<body>

<!--start main container -->

<div id="main" class="asd">

    <div id="header">

    <?php  if ($c->isEditMode()) { ?>
        <div style="min-height: 80px">
    <?php  } ?>

        <h1 id="logo">
        <a title="asd" href="testing.php">
        <img height="131" width="384" alt="" src="xx.jpg" title="asd">      
        </a>                
        </h1>



    </div>
```

On the HTML side.. It looks like this :

```
<div id="faded">
<div id="slider" class="nivoSliders"><img src="img0.png" alt="" /> <a href="http://dev7studios.com"><img title="#htmlcaption" src="img1.png" alt="" /></a> <img title="This is an example of a caption" src="img2.png" alt="" /> <img src="img3.png" alt="" /></div>
<div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption"><strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.</div>
</div>
```

I have tried putting the javascript srcs to the php and html sides of the website but the website wont load for the php, and my administrative controls gets removed while I'm still logged in as admin on the html side. I'm thinking it could be a jQuery conflict and have tried the jQuery.noConflict() function as well...

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, my edit function (as an admin) became static and 4 images were displayed (i have 4 pictures) for when I put the <script src="nivoslideretc.js"</script> after the </div> in html. As I'm using a CMS system, the <head> tags are in my header.php which I've pasted in my original message. Oh and ignore the </script> before the </head> tag. That was where I had my <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>